# How To precisely identify my Beep sounds? BIOS Beep Codes for Desktop Boards - What do these actually sound like?

Tags: boot, audio, motherboard, bios, hardware-failure

Trying to sort through a bunch of old machines with various errors and variety of sounds while booting, including BIOS beep sounds.

At times, instead of clearly pointing to one "condition", I have to place the beep sounds in various (ambiguous) buckets, leaving me confused.

Is there a reference audio repository for this entire list?

Can someone point to an actual clear recording of these sounds?

http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/boards-and-kits/000005473.html

> **BIOS Beep Codes for Desktop Boards**
>   Last Reviewed: 10-May-2016
>   Article ID: 000005473
>
> The BIOS uses audible beep codes or visible blink patterns to signal
>   status messages and error messages indicating recoverable errors that
>   occur during the POST.
>
> Click  on the questions to expand the content:
>
> - **Audible beep codes**
> - Visible LED blink patterns
> - **Beep codes for discontinued (legacy) desktop boards**

PS: The linked duplicate is for a specific sound on a specific piece of hardware.

I am/ was looking for an Audio reference, not just a textual reference of how "ALL codes" sound as I have a bunch of machines down that need to be checked and the textual chart (Intel link) is not always clearly translatable from the variety of Audio sounds that at times are not a clear one to one on the text/ table reference. Looking for a General Audio reference chart if any.

Comment: Beep codes are usually documented in the manuals of the respective hardware.

Comment: Beeping error codes are different per manufacturer. There used to be a standard, but got abandoned. I should have a book somewhere that has these standards, which is why I know about them, but we're talking about really old pc's here. 80286, etc.

Comment: I've already googled and pointed to the list of Intel Desktop Beep codes etc (linked above). So, I'm not asking for documentation manuals or standards document. I already linked to the "written" list for this, but the sounds from troubling Motherboards can at times be hard to discern. So, was looking for an auditory reference.

Comment: @Dave - I've already googled and pointed to the list of Intel Desktop Beep codes etc (linked above). PS: Thanks. I was hoping for a proper auditory reference sheet, but I guess I'll have to go with the tip.

Comment: @Dave - There is reason why Sounds, Music, Pictures, Colors are represented by Actuals and no just descriptions of them in Text. Trying to discern sound from one Tuning fork to another needs an auditory reference in addition to text.

Answer (score 1):

First not to be a jerk but ... http://bfy.tw/7dZ2  (yes "let me google that for you")  the upstart of which.. add the word "youtube" at the end of your search and you're likely to get hits at Youtube, which gives you audio and video of said beeps.

That said .. this video (started 22 seconds in) gives a fairly clear beep code, then pauses, and gives it again as its supposed to for this condition..

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=atzg6oJtMpA&t=22

what does it mean? there are a few general codes, but there could be specific differences.  AND while that link gives you a nice clear indicator (1 long 3 short - generally a memory error) there are bios makers that dont time their beeps well, and are so short you end up having to force the code multiple times.

http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

This site has a few bios's general beep patterns, but keep in mind a motherboard manufacturer can alter the codes because they purpose build the bios from pieces of code and may have a reason to alter general codes so you must check your motherboard manufacturer's manual.

Comment: I've already googled and pointed to the list of Intel Desktop Beep codes etc (linked above). 
PS: Thanks. I was hoping for a proper auditory reference sheet, but I guess I'll have to go with your youtube tip